# Is it possible to generate random IBAN number (Seleinium C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have fill the the random account number in textbox.My code below

```
        string AccountNumberStr = "******************";
        personEditPage.FillBankAccount(AccountNumberStr);
```

Problem is for each time when i'm running the test i have to change the account number manually.There is any possiblity to replace using IBAN generator ?!

Comment: could `AccountNumberStr ` be a random value?

Comment: yes but it should be in IBAN format

Comment: and how is `IBAN` format?

Comment: NL91ABNA041716*****

Comment: it could have different formates, but i guess you only need the *Netherland*. am i right?

Comment: yes Your right:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pattern in generating the IBAN code for each country, such as:

[image]

So, you need to know how to generate BBAN first. So, all of these things makes your code more and more difficult.

**But**

I suggest you to use your slenium to get the value from [this site](https://www.generateiban.com/test-iban/). Since you already, lunch your selenium browser, it wouldn't be difficult for you to navigate to the url :

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.generateiban.com/test-iban/"); 
string AccountNumberStr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="iban"]");
```

There is a drawback for it, because it makes your app slow, but it is short, and easy to understand

Comment: @Mutu Arron didn't this answer help?

Comment: yes Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can check [THIS LINK](https://github.com/sinkien/IBAN4Net)

It is a library which is producing random IBAN Numbers. It is doing what you need and is also written in C# so you can take some ides from there :)....Good luck!

Comment: _"and it doesn't support random IBAN generation, yet"_ - 2 years ago

Comment: There is a library that for random Iban generation:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/IbanNet

C#: new IbanGenerator().Generate(countryCode: "GB"); 

However it doesn't support all countries.
Supported: AL, AD, AT, AZ, BH, BE, BA, BR, BG, BI, CR, HR, CY, CZ, DK, DO, EG, EE, FO, FI, FR, GE, DE, GI, GR, GL, GT, HU, IS, IE, IL, IT, JO, KZ, KW, LB, LI, LT, LU, MK, MT, MR, MU, MD, MC, ME, NL, NO, PK, PL, PS, PT, QA, XK, RO, LC, SM, ST, SA, SC, SK, SI, ES, SE, CH, TL, TN, TR, UA, AE, GB, VG;
Unupported: DZ, AO, BJ, BF, CM, CV, TD, KM, CG, GA, HN, IR, CI, MG, ML, MA, MZ, NI, NE, SN, TG